# Is "at your convenience" correct?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, grammaticality

I created a problem on GitHub but the developers are too busy. I want to told them not to rush.
Are the following sentences OK and natural?
Also, What should I use if "at your convenience" is wrong?

- Please take a look at report at your convenience.
- Please fix report at your convenience.
- You can fix report at your convenience.
- Fix report at your convenience.

Answer (score 2):

The phrases are not wrong, but I would simply say "there is no hurry". Note that any such statement risks the developers giving the report their lowest priority.

The phrase "at your convenience" has been used in military fiction where a senior ranked person orders a lower ranked person to do something, but it is not needed immediately. The phrase allows the lower ranked person to complete their current task, or at least stop at a convenient point, before following the order.

By the way the phrase "at your convenience" gives rise to possibilities of unwanted toilet humour - check the definitions of "convenience" in your dictionary. This unexpected usage may be more common in the UK than elsewhere.

Comment: Firstly, ‘at your convenience’ can be used in toilet humour, but doesn’t (at least to me) necessarily call it to mind. Secondly, it’s worth mentioning that ‘report’ in the OP’s examples requires either ‘the’ or ‘my’ before it to sound natural.